# Why are these two C# .NET Framework Applications not causing a deadlock on a SQL Server database?

Tags: c#, sql-server, database-deadlocks

I have two C# .NET Framework applications that are both operating on a single SQL Server database. Both applications and the SQL Server database are running on my local PC. Both applications run the following code forever:

```
try
            {
                //Continuously and rapidly run select statements so that we can produce a deadlock condition
                // with another process
                while (true)
                {
                    using (SqlConnection sqlConnection = new SqlConnection(connectionString))
                    {
                        sqlConnection.Open();
                        RunNonQuery(sql1, sqlConnection);
                        RunSelect(sql2, sqlConnection);
                        RunNonQuery(sql3, sqlConnection);
                        Console.WriteLine("No exception encountered yet...");
                    }
                }
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Exception encountered:");
                Console.WriteLine(ex.Message);
                Console.ReadLine();
                Environment.Exit(1);
            }
```

The only difference is that program 1 uses the following sql statements:

```
string sql1 = @"BEGIN TRAN;
UPDATE SomeTable
SET Message = 'Some Message'
WHERE Id = 1
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10.000'";

string sql2 = @"SELECT *
FROM SomeOtherTable";

string sql3 = @"ROLLBACK TRAN;";
```

While program two uses the following statements:

```
string sql1 = @"BEGIN TRAN;
UPDATE SomeOtherTable
SET Message = 'Some Message'
WHERE Id = 1
WAITFOR DELAY '00:00:10.000'";

string sql2 = @"SELECT *
FROM SomeTable";

string sql3 = @"ROLLBACK TRAN;";
```

I am starting the applications within 10 seconds of each other. I expect that program 1 will start by holding a lock on SomeTable and program 2 will start by holding a lock on SomeOtherTable. 10 seconds after program 1 starts, I expect program 1 to begin waiting for program 2 to release the lock on SomeOtherTable. 10 seconds after program 2 starts, program 2 should begin waiting on program 1 to release the lock on SomeTable, at which point a deadlock should occur.

I am inexperienced in database locking and concurrent database .NET application interaction. I suspect that part of the reason I can't figure this out is that I don't know what kind of locks that the queries I've written are holding and/or there might be some setting in the SQL Server database or database connection that I have unwittingly changed somewhere along the way.

The version of the .NET Framework I am using is .NET Framework v4.8

Comment: How many rows match the `WHERE` condition of the `UPDATE`? And exactly what indexes do you have on the tables? Are you using parameterized queries? What happens if you execute these three batches as one big batch?

Comment: Do you have `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` isolation activated on the database?

Comment: I reproduced the scenario, and get those expected deadlock exceptions. As Charliface mentioned there must be at least one row updated on `SomeOtherTable` and `SomeTable` to produce a lock. I executed on two separate sesions in ssms with `ReadCommitted` isolation level. @AlwaysLearning ¿How can I check if my database has `READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT` isolation activated?

Comment: @MauricioOrtega see the [ALTER TABLE # READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/alter-database-transact-sql-set-options?view=sql-server-ver16#read_committed_snapshot--on--off-) docs.

Comment: `select name, is_read_committed_snapshot_on  from sys.databases`

Comment: Argh, that would be `ALTER DATABASE`, not `ALTER TABLE`. Late night...

Comment: @MauricioOrtega Exactly one row matches the WHERE condition of the UPDATE in each query. The only indexes on either table are the CLUSTERED indexes where created on each table's primary key columns, which are both the 'Id' column in their respective tables. I do not know if the queries are being parameterized. What are the implications of the queries being parameterized or not? If I run the individual SQL statements as one statement through the two programs, no exception is encountered.

Comment: @AlwaysLearning READ_COMMITTED_SNAPSHOT is not set

Comment: Do you have `AttachDbFilename` or `User Instance` in the connection string?

Comment: @Charlieface No